# Is there any way facebook page access token of by page id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-access-token

Is there any way I can get access token of any page by page id, I should be able to post on page behalf of admin?

Comment: What do you mean by “any” page – even pages where you’re not an admin …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't want to be admin of your clients' pages:

1. You could create a page so that your clients login to Facebook and
   grant permissions to your app.
2. Then you can get the page access token and save it in your DB.
3. Finally use that access token to **post directly to each page as
   admin without being you the actual admin**.

Quoting [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#overview):

> To obtain a page access token you need to start by obtaining a user
>   access token and asking for the manage_pages permission. Once you have
>   the user access token you then get the page access token via the Graph
>   API.

To get user access token (supposing you are logged in to fbk and have granted permissions to your App):

```
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if(!$user) {
        $login_url_params = array(
             'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages',
             'fbconnect' =>  1,
             'redirect_uri' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        );
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
        //redirect to the login URL on facebook
        header("Location: {$login_url}");
    }
```

Don't forget get to a time extended access token

```
    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

With that token you can get the page token via the API:

```
    $accounts = $facebook->api(
       '/me/accounts',
       'GET',
       array(
          'access_token' => $access_token
       )
    );
```

$accounts will be an associative array with all the info of the pages you admin (including the tokens for each page). To get the token of an specific page knowing its ID:

```
    $accounts = $accounts['data'];
foreach($accounts as $account){
    if( $account['id'] == $pagId ){
        //$pagId would be the ID of the page you want to use

        //This is the token of the page with the ID $pagId
        $page_access_token = $account['access_token'],
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cultivo, it make me sense. You are right to get user access token with manage_pages permission. I know I can get it with apps, Is there any other way to get user access_token with manage_pages permission in a secure way that user should not understand it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question... You're trying to post from a user that may or may not be the admin to a Facebook page and using a App access token instead of the User access token? What do you mean with 'way that user should not understand it'? To make secure Facebook says that posting using App access token should always be done from your server.

Comment: yes You've understood. Basically I want to make post as a admin on all pages related to weight loss. So I'm not admin of their pages. So is there any to make it done?

Comment: In order to post as admin you need a page access token and the only way to get it to be admin of that page. You could ask the admin of the page to grant permissions to your App via a login page. I updated my answer with more info. Hope it helps.

Comment: _"Basically I want to make post as a admin on all pages related to weight loss. So I'm not admin of their pages."_ - so basically you want to __spam__. No, of course there is no way to do this.